# Can't get VB script to add new rows in Excel document

Tags: excel, vba

First of all, I'll state that I'm new to VB...  I have a script that I'm using and for some reason cannot get it to add data from multiple emails to new rows.  It seems to maybe just overwrite the same row each time...

Basically, I have about 500 emails in my inbox that all are from form submissions.  All have data formatted like this:

02sender_last_name:  Jones
01sender_first_name:  Bob

etc...  I want to take that data and put it into a nice excel spreadsheet.  This is the code I have right now - but again, it's not putting data from multiple emails into different rows.  Any help for a newbie?  :-)

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyToExcel()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim vText As Variant
Dim sText As String
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim rCount As Long
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Const strPath As String = "C:\test\test.xlsx" 'the path of the workbook

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    bXStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
'Open the workbook to input the data
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Process each selected record
For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    sText = olItem.Body
    vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
   rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    rCount = rCount + 1

    'Check each line of text in the message body
    For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1
        If InStr(1, vText(i), "01sender_first_name:") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If

        If InStr(1, vText(i), "02sender_last_name: ") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "03contact_license_number: ") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "06contact_phone_area_code: ") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "07contact_phone_prefix: ") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "08contact_phone_number: ") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("F" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "city: ") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("G" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

    If InStr(1, vText(i), "email: ") > 0 Then
        vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
        xlSheet.Range("H" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
    End If

Next i
xlWB.Save
Next olItem
xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
If bXStarted Then
    xlApp.Quit
End If
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You mean you seem not to be iterating properly in the selected Outlook items or you cannot add new rows in Excel? .Selection returns a collection of selected items. So if you've got only one item selected in Outlook, that'll be it.

Comment: Try the solution of Stepan. And do the save action, `xlWB.Save
`, after the `for each` loop, not with each iteration unless you have a very good reason. This will speed up your loop instantly.

Comment: Thanks, AutomatedChaos!  That was a great suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to change this

```
'Process each selected record
For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    sText = olItem.Body
    vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
   rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    rCount = rCount + 1
```

to this:

```
'Process each selected record
rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    sText = olItem.Body
    vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
    rCount = rCount + 1
```